# I want to set a Master to Turn-on and Turn-off ShortDesc Notofication in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to set a Master Turn-on and Turn-off ShortDesc Notification in ADF. For Ex. If you click-on the Field If there is Short Desc for the Field, it will show as a Notification,  If i want to see the ShortDesc Notification, I can turn-on and if i dont need, Turn-off. Is there a way to do that.?

Please help me with this.?

Comment: You have been posting a number of questions on which you've got answers back, but there was no feedback from you. In case the solution was helpful you should mark it as such, otherwise if the solutions didn't work for you, you should provide more details with what went wrong. Is the least we can do, when people spend their own time answering questions.

Comment: I hope almost for all the post im giving proper reply. If you have doubts chk it again. Except one...

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you are reading NOTIF_ON value from a database table - user preferences, lets say. You can implement 'ShortDesc Notification' as an ADF popup, something like this:

```
<af:document id="d1" title="Report">

     <af:resource type="javascript">
            function openPopup() {
             var notifOn = evt.getSource().getProperty("NOTIF_ON");
             if(notifOn) {
               var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('p1');
               popup.show();
              }
            }
     </af:resource>

     <af:form id="f1">
       <af:outputText value="#{bindings.Field.inputValue}">
          <af:clientListener type="click" method="openPopup"/>
          <af:clientAttribute name="NOTIF_ON"
                               value="#{bindings.NotifOn.inputValue}"/>

       </af:outputText>
       <af:popup id="p1" contentDelivery="immediate">
        <af:dialog id="d2" type="none" title="ShortDesc Notification">
           <af:outputText value=#{bindings.ShortDesc.inputValue}" id="ot11"/>
        </af:dialog>
       </af:popup>
    </af:form>

  </af:document>
```

Furthermore, toggling NOTIF ON and OFF is a matter of saving a boolean into a table, therefore trivial.

Comment: No. What im Asking is, Letz take, In a form All the Fields having ShortDesc Notification. When user click on the field, it will show a notification with whatever text/binding value we've given. If im designing a app with this, Some customer wants that notification to be displayed, some dont want. There should me master like On/Off.  Who-ever wants get assistance about what to enter in the field they can turn-on to see the notifications.Some customer wont like to get notification in the page, those people can turn-off and start filling the fields. This is what the exact issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Notification"? I was presuming you want to implement a popup message, firing onclick event.

Comment: When you click on the Field, it will show you, something like "Please enter your name"... Something like that..